# How to select using Criteria Builder

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

I want to query the following **PSQL** script, but using Criteria Builder:

**PostgreSQL**

`SELECT ts.domain, ts."data" -> 'id' as id FROM myScheme.myServiceTable ts;`

I've tried this so far with criteria, but it's contantly throwing an annoying error message

**Criteria Builder code**

```
public final CriteriaQuery<Object[]> getServiceInfo() {

    final CriteriaBuilder builder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();
    final CriteriaQuery<Object[]> criteria = builder.createQuery(Object[].class);
    final Root<ServiceTable> rootBooking = criteria.from(ServiceTable.class);

    criteria.multiselect(
         builder.function("jsonb_extract_path_text", 
                           String.class, 
                           rootBooking.get("data"), 
                           builder.literal("id")
         ).alias("id"),
         rootBooking.get("domain")
    );
}
```

**Error message:**

```
org.hibernate.QueryException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode \r\n \\-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: 'function (jsonb_extract_path_text)'\r\n    +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'jsonb_extract_path_text' {originalText=jsonb_extract_path_text}\r\n    \\-[EXPR_LIST] SqlNode: 'exprList'\r\n
```

If anybody knows how can I query what I mentioned before, I'll appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a function that is unknown to Hibernate in the select clause you will have to cast the expression:

```
builder.function(
    "jsonb_extract_path_text", 
    Integer.class, // Some other type so that casting works
    rootBooking.get("data"), 
    builder.literal("id")
).as(String.class).alias("id")
```

In Hibernate 6 this is not necessary anymore. If you don't want the cast, the register the function as `SQLFunction` in the `Dialect`.